# Git log records duplicated in master branch from develop branch

Tags: git, github

How to avoid updated duplicated commits if my develop branch didn't closed after merged into master.

As example, there has 3 branch i worked on

1. master
2. develop
3. feature

I will always checkout from **develop** to **feature** branch to work my update. And then, I will `git rebase develop` in my feature branch to make sure the develop branch is the latest.

Second, i will merge the feature branch into develop branch in github. And merged develop branch into master.

Checked in the master git log results:

```
commit 1f5eaf26c9db271b6fb
Auhtor: Wilker <96217606+Wilker1216@users.noreply.github.com>
Date: Thu Mar 24 16:35:10 2022 +0800
 Update Incentive Trip Checkbox (#250)
    
    * Create Export View Component
    
    * rebase with master
    
    * Fixes text typo

    * Update Create View Show

commit 68d7a33ae330
Author: Wilker <96217606+Wilker1216@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 24 15:08:15 2022 +0800

Fixes Typo Api (#248)

  * Create Export View Component
    
  * rebase with master
    
  * Fixes text typo

  * Update Create View Show
```

Comment: You made two different commits (note the different hash IDs) with two different *log messages* as well (note that one says `Fixes Typo Api (#248)` and the other does not). If you didn't want to make two separate commits, don't have made two separate commits. Or, if you didn't want the log messages to look similar, don't have made them look similar.

Comment: "And merged develop branch into master." I don't think so. I think you are telling GitHub to "squash" or "rebase". That is _not a merge_. Duplicating commits is exactly what it does. It's a bad strategy when you have multiple long lived branches. To avoid this sort of trouble, truly _merge_ develop into master.

Comment: @matt Github webpage there show "merge" button into develop.. it is not real merge?

Comment: Merge is a real merge! But two other options, rebase and merge, and squash and merge, are not actually merges at all.